# Alternative to replace the "hidden input"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input, hidden

All say that 'input hidden' is not safe, but what would be another alternative to replace the 'hidden input' and send information hidden in the form?
(I use in my application php, javascrip, jquery...)

Comment: use javascript variable to hold the so called "hidden input" value

Comment: the alternative would be to not `submit()` the form and use javascript (or jQuery) to get all the form information add whatever you want to it and send it wherever you want

Comment: where you found hidden field is not safe?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam (example) if the price is a hidden field, then a TV for $999 could be changed by a customer who knows how (not hard) to be $1, then purchased for $1 if validations aren't present on the server side

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing intrinsically unsafe with the input element with type hidden as it is, and it serves its purpose well (retain and send a hidden value along with the form). It is just as "safe" as any form control can be (prone to user tampering, etc).

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield" value="xxx" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

As with any other form data, however, you must properly validate its submitted value server-side, that's all there is to it.